# How do I store Multiple Select Data in the DB?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm working with a 'multiple'  editor. I can store the values in the DB and format the values on output etc no problem...

The behaviour I'm experiencing when editing the multiple select column is:

- Click on the cell
- Editor is called
- List drops down with selectable values
  **then...**
- Click out of the cell
- Data is lost (effectively replaced with empty string)

I think I know the reason why this is happening...
Tabulator should take the data values and 'select' them in the drop down so that the 'Old Value' object is updated.

It seems that if the initial 'selected' values are not output from the DB in the correct format, then Tabulator does not 'select' them on render.

I need to know how one should store multiple values in the DB to get the correct behaviour on output.

Any idea on how to make this work please?

I should note, that if the DB value is a single one the Tabulator picks it up no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
cellEditing: function (cell) {
                var a = cell.getValue();
                if (!a === null && a.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                    cell.setValue(a.split(','), false);
                }
            },
```

So, after digging into the edit.js file, I see that the editor requires an array before editing.

Using the above code worked for me. I just made sure that I saved the selected options imploded (php) with a comma separator and no spaces.

```
'fabricproperties' => (is_array($v->fabricproperties) ? implode(',', $v->fabricproperties) : $v->fabricproperties)
```

I'm no js expert, so by all means feel free to correct me if there''s a better way.